# datastax agent eats cpu after upgrade from 5.1.1 to 5.2.0

Tags: datastax-enterprise

after upgrade datastax agent from 5.1.1 to 5.2.0(or 5.1.2/5.1.3), it begins eat cpu with spikes.

env: ubuntu 14.04 x64,  openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 (sorry, cannot post image from our monitoring system)

4DC setup (1 node backup - no load, 1 node solr - search, 2x4 nodes with cassa)

Comment: Hi Mihail, ideally you'd have a separate question for the mutations issue. Can you split it out and place the link here as a comment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594028/dse-4-6-to-4-7-1-mutation-messages-dropped-in-last-5000ms about strange with "1 mutation droppped"