# DSE 4.6 to 4.7: 1 MUTATION messages dropped in last 5000ms

Tags: datastax-enterprise

after upgrade our cluster(4DC, ubuntu 14.04 x64, cpp-driver 2.0.1 as client in our app) from 4.6 to 4.7, got message in logs on few nodes with small load "MessagingService.java:888 - 1 MUTATION messages dropped in last 5000ms" with 1 Pending HintedHandoff notice in thread pool dump

what i try:
run "nodetool truncatehints" on each running node in cluster
changing openjdk to oracle jdk(1.7.0_76-b13)
decommission node and rejoin it

how to find this mutation/hint and drop it?

side note:
we do not increase load ( version 4.6 work ok with this load)
we do not decrease node count
we have ssd backed storage

fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9129

Answer (score 3):

Dropped mutations usually mean that your disk is not able to keep up with your ingest. You may be interested, at this point, to find out if there are any threadpools backing up (usually flushwriters if this is an IO issue). This is why cassandra will log the treadpool status at that moment.

Cassandra is built on a SEDA architecture with multiple thread pools that can handle up to a certain number of parallel tasks. Pending threadpool tasks pile up when there are more active tasks than the pool can concurrently handle. They will eventually get processed once the system has resources to do so, or dropped under extreme circumstances.

To see the current status of your thread pools use `nodetool tpstats`. Most likely your hints task has already been processed.

The fact that you were accumulating hints implies that some of your nodes were down and hints are being replayed for consistency now that the node has come back up.

Your core issue is the dropped mutations. Consider one of the following actions if you continue to see this:

- Add nodes
- Get better storage (don't use shared storage-- I.E. amazon
  EBS, ssd's are faster than spinning disks)
- Decrease your workload
- Make sure you are loading with best practices (good data model that
  spreads out the load, a datastax driver that has loadbalancing etc. )

Comment: i'll agree with you, but. previous dse 4.6.7 do not have such problems( as i state in question - there is only one pending job in thread pool - HintedHandoff others are zero (active and pending). this servers use ssd as disk backend, i don't see I/O time spikes in monitoring(5min avg 10-20 IOs for read/write), disk load less than 1%. may be you mean `nodetool tpstats` instead of `nodetool status`(1)?

Comment: and second: how to see from where this hint coming from? from what node? ip? uuid? it there any way to drop this hint? may be originating node cannot transfer this hint? due to some kind of self limits? but why destination node writes in log about dropped mutation?

Comment: I did! Thanks. Is the hint still pending after the fact or just in the logs?

Comment: Check in cqlsh system.hints

Comment: You could do a thread dump to see what's blocking the hint. Or I bet a rolling restart would clear it.

Comment: what kind of thread i looking for? HintedHandoff:X? in what state? TIMED_WAITING ? if so, here is http://pastebin.com/N3vH0TvW jstack dump. rolling restart do not help. i have one pending HintedHandoff on each of 10 nodes( with 0 rows in system.hints table on all nodes.

Comment: Could you drop the entire jstack output?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2hUPRivR 1.1.1 - DC1 ips, 2.2.2 - DC2 ips, 3.3.3 - DC999 one node (from where this dump)